# Moment.js - Date Granularity

Tags: momentjs, granularity

In moment.js, if I write:

```
moment('1998').format('DD MMM YYYY');
```

I get `31 Dec 1997`. It seems like it rounds the date backwards. I would like to to say `01 Jan 1998`.

How can I do this? It doesn't seem to have much documentation for granularity.

Comment: Can you include hour/minutes in your format to see if somehow a UTC decorator is getting in the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should also give you a warning, as moment's use of 'guess which format type I'm using' function is [deprecated](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407).

It's probably guessing the right date, but due to the time difference in your timezone, it's giving this output. Try adding `.utc()` to your call (`moment('1998-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD').utc().format('DD MMM YYYY')`).

Comment: It was the `utc()` that did it. Thanks. And that they depricated it totally sucks :( - I get that it's unpredictable, but it's great for parsing user input.

Comment: Hmmm... I'd much rather have something that is reliable than chasing bugs for which for instance months and days are mixed up. You can still roll your own heuristic by defining a list of formats and run through them. This is much more transparent and deterministic.

Comment: True, true. And i've done that before, but you'd think a library like Moment.js would also do that as well, and if it did, it would do it 1000x better than I would be able to.